# Partition Proof

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, summation, problem-solving, products

Let $\lambda$ be a partition of $N$ of rank $r$.  How can I show that:

$$\sum_wx^\lambda(w)=f^\lambda(-1)^{t(\lambda)}\prod^r_{i=1}(\lambda_i-1)!(\lambda'_i-1)!$$

where $w$ ranges over all permutations in $\mathfrak{S}_N$ with exactly $r$ cycles, and where $t(\lambda)=\sum^r_{i=1}(\lambda'-1)$.

I'm not trying to ask for someone to do this for me, I'm just asking for a general hint.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could start by explaning your question better. Does $\Bbb G_N$ designate the symemtric group on $N$ letters? I've never seen this notation used before. Also, I would read $x^\lambda$ as a monomial with multi-exponent $\lambda$, but I don't know how to apply monomials to permutations (unless you mean acting by the permutation on the monomial), and to make things worse the $x$'s are absent in the right hand side.

Comment: Agree with Marc. Never seen ${\Bbb G}_N$ used for $S_n$ before. Don't know what $x^\lambda(w)$ means. Is $f^\lambda$ the number of standard tableaux of shape $\lambda$? Is $\lambda'$ the dual partition?

Comment: there I corrected it, I was trying to find the correct latex

Comment: I double checked it, it's correct I didn't make a typo....

Comment: Try double checking the comments. More than just the ${\Bbb G}_N$ was mentioned.

Comment: Yes, $x^\lambda$ as a monomial with multi-exponent $\lambda$; RHS doesn't have $x$

Comment: My first guess was that it was $\chi_\lambda(w)$, the character of the $S_n$-irrep corresponding to $\lambda$ evaluated at $w$, but I guess that's not correct. How do you apply a monomial $x^\lambda$ to a permutation $w$? (Perhaps the answer to that will also answer how $x$s could be on the LHS but not the RHS.) Is my guess about the meaning of $f^\lambda$ correct? More lightheartedly, is there a reason you won't explain what your terms are without interrogation? If this problem comes from somewhere, you could probably give an explicit citation and forego having to explain yourself somewhat.

Comment: It's on the homework set for combinatorics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $\lambda\in Par$ and $n\in\mathbb{P}$:

$$s_\lambda(1^n)=\prod_{u\in\lambda}\frac{n+c(u)}{h(u)}$$

where we define the hook length $h(u)$ of $\lambda$ at $u$ by $h(u)=\lambda_i+\lambda'_j-i-j+1$ and the content $c(u)$ of $\lambda$ at $u=(i,j)$ by $c(u)=j-i$.

We know that:

$$\frac{1}{N!}\sum_{w\in\mathfrak{S}_N}x^\lambda(w)n^{c(w)}=\prod_{u\in\lambda}\frac{n+c(u)}{h(u)}$$

The coefficient of $n^r$on LHS is equal to $\frac{1}{N!}\sum_wx^\lambda(w)$.  Thus we have $x^\lambda(v)=0$.  So the LHS is divisible by $n^r$.  There're $r$ factors equal to $n$ in the numerator of LHS, coming from that the $r$ diagonal terms $u=(i,i)$.

So, the coefficient of $n^r$ on RHS would be:

$$\frac{\prod_{u\in\lambda,u\neq(i,i)}c(u)}{\prod_{u\in\lambda}h(u)}=\frac{f^\lambda}{N!}\prod_{u\in\lambda, u\neq(i,i)}c(u).$$

Now we can see that this last product is simply $$(-1)^{t(\lambda)}\prod^r_{i=1}(\lambda_i-1)!(\lambda'_i-1)!.\ \ \ \ \square$$

Comment: Thanks for the proof!  You rock!